# Is there any way to convert a junir testcase into a html testcase in selenium

Tags: selenium-ide

I export testcase as j unit and i made some changes.then again i want to convert the j unit as a testcase to open in IDE is there any way to do that thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to convert junit or any other framework testcase back to HTML format but it is possible to convert HTML testcases to other frameworks.

1.Open Selenium IDE, go to options and then options again.
2.At the bottom click on the option: **Enable experimental features**.
 
(This allows you to convert your recorded testcases to any other format.)
3.Go to selenium IDE and choose options again and check under **format**.